# Creating a 6 bit crc using boost

Tags: c++, boost, crc

I'm new to CRCs, boost and more of a java developer for that matter. I'm trying to use the the crc.hpp boost library to create a 6 bit crc calculated based on only two bits. First is this possible?

It seems that the Theoretical CRC Computer can be used to process a specific number of bits, however I'm unclear how to specify a 6 bit result. Help please.

Comment: Why would your result be larger than your input?

Comment: Agreed kind of unusual. However I'm just following the header specification for a msg type. I questioned it and was simply told we are not able to change that value.

Comment: This comment completely changes the question.  You're not trying to compute _a_ 6-bit CRC.  It sounds like you need to compute _the_ 6-bit CRC required by the header specification.  There are many possible 6-bit CRCs, with different polynomials, initialization values, post-processing, input bit ordering, and output bit ordering.  So what does the specification say?

Comment: Yes again you are correct. However the specification has now been changed. The 2 bit data will now be padded with 6 bits and the 8 bit crc will be created based on 8 bits of data. Again, much thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your input is based on 2 actual bits and not two bytes, this should work:

```
const int initial_remainder = 0xBAADF00D;

unsigned char input = 0x3;

boost::crc_basic<6> checksum(initial_remainder);
checksum.process_bits(input, 2);

printf("%i", checksum.checksum());
```

You still need to figure out what the initial remainder should be, though.

Comment: Yes two bits not bytes, let me give that a go. Thanks!

Comment: This code functions but my checksum result seems incorrect. I am getting single character results or nothing at all. Perhaps I'm still missing something.

Comment: @user1464251 unless you give us expected results we cannot answer this fully. It's entirely possible that your initial remainder is incorrect, causing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

This should just be a custom code that maximizes the Hamming distance between four byte values.  It would be a table of four 8-bit values indexed by the two bits as a number in 0..3.

A set of values (there 280 such sets) that maximizes the minimum Hamming distance between any two of the four values is: `0x00, 0x4f, 0xb3, 0xfc`.  The minimum Hamming distance is 5.  The high two bits of those values is the two-bit index in order.

Comment: I'm not certain I fully understand what you are saying. I understand the Hamming distance concept. Since I am only concerned with 2 bits, a Hamming distance of 5 exceeds my requirement, good.
I don't understand what you mean when you state 'between four byte values'. Why four bytes? I'm clear on indexing them.
Also, how did you obtain 280 such sets?

Comment: 2 bits have four possible values.  You are mapping to 8-bit values (stated as 2 bits of data plus a 6-bit CRC), hence mapping to four bytes.

Comment: A brute force search turns up 280 sorted sets with the first byte being zero.  You can exclusive-or all the bytes with the same value to get other sets with the same Hamming distances, so there are really more sets.  In any case, you need only one set.